# Deleting custom styles in Excel workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am working in a large xlsb (Microsoft Excel Binary Workbook). There is a large number of custom styles in the file.

I think the styles were unintentionally included when worksheets were copied from other workbooks. I would like to delete all of the custom styles. The manual approach (right click and delete) doesn't work.

I searched online for VBA solutions and found the three macros below.
When I run the macros they immediately jump to the MsgBox without having deleted any of the custom styles.

```vb
Sub clear_all_styles()
    Dim styT As Style
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each styT In ActiveWorkbook.Styles
        If Not styT.BuiltIn Then
            If styT.Name <> "1" Then styT.Delete
        End If
    Next styT
    MsgBox "Macro completed" 'can be commented out
End Sub


Sub DeleteStyles()
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each sty In ActiveWorkbook.Styles
        If Not sty.BuiltIn Then
            sty.Delete
        End If
    Next sty
    MsgBox "Macro completed" 'can be commented out
End Sub
   

Sub StyleKiller()
    Dim st As Style
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each st In ActiveWorkbook.Styles
        If Not st.BuiltIn Then
            st.Delete
        End If
    Next
    On Error GoTo 0
    MsgBox "Macro completed" 'can be commented out
End Sub
```

After more online searching I found the solution below. This deleted the vast majority of the custom styles.

```vb
Sub RebuildDefaultStyles()
    
    'The purpose of this macro is to remove all styles in the active
    'workbook and rebuild the default styles.
    'It rebuilds the default styles by merging them from a new workbook.
    
    'Dimension variables.
    Dim MyBook As Workbook
    Dim tempBook As Workbook
    Dim CurStyle As Style
    
    'Set MyBook to the active workbook.
    Set MyBook = ActiveWorkbook
    On Error Resume Next
    'Delete all the styles in the workbook.
    For Each CurStyle In MyBook.Styles
        'If CurStyle.Name <> "Normal" Then CurStyle.Delete
        Select Case CurStyle.Name
            Case "20% - Accent1", "20% - Accent2", _
              "20% - Accent3", "20% - Accent4", "20% - Accent5", "20% - Accent6", _
              "40% - Accent1", "40% - Accent2", "40% - Accent3", "40% - Accent4", _
              "40% - Accent5", "40% - Accent6", "60% - Accent1", "60% - Accent2", _
              "60% - Accent3", "60% - Accent4", "60% - Accent5", "60% - Accent6", _
              "Accent1", "Accent2", "Accent3", "Accent4", "Accent5", "Accent6", _
              "Bad", "Calculation", "Check Cell", "Comma", "Comma [0]", "Currency", _
              "Currency [0]", "Explanatory Text", "Good", "Heading 1", "Heading 2", _
              "Heading 3", "Heading 4", "Input", "Linked Cell", "Neutral", "Normal", _
              "Note", "Output", "Percent", "Title", "Total", "Warning Text"
              'Do nothing, these are the default styles
            Case Else
                CurStyle.Delete
        End Select
    
    Next CurStyle
    
    'Open a new workbook.
    Set tempBook = Workbooks.Add
    
    'Disable alerts so you may merge changes to the Normal style
    'from the new workbook.
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    'Merge styles from the new workbook into the existing workbook.
    MyBook.Styles.Merge Workbook:=tempBook
    
    'Enable alerts.
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    'Close the new workbook.
    tempBook.Close
    
End Sub
```

Approximately 20 styles remain which can neither be deleted by the macro nor by manual action.

The console output from one of the styles that was not deleted.

AeE­ [0]_INQUIRY ¿µ¾÷AßAø

It's a bunch of symbols but some of the names seems to also just include an underline as the only symbol "_".

Comment: Would be good to get rid of the `On Error Resume Next` command and check if any runtime error occurs. The first three codes should work also (they all do the same) - only question is if you always want to work on the Active Workbook.

Comment: What "Special signs" do you refer to? And why are you obsessed with the thought that you need to remove the built-in styles? Disk space? Have you tried to call delete unconditionally (by removing *If ...*  and *Case ...* conditions) on all styles?

Comment: I just tried with a modified code, removing the condition to not delete built-in styles, and all styles except "Normal" seem to vanish. Running same code a second time only lists "Normal" style.

Answer (score 1):

perhapst deleting by a subroutine gives more information:

```
Option Explicit

Sub DelStyles()
Dim st As Style
For Each st In ActiveWorkbook.Styles
    If Not st.BuiltIn Then
      DelSingleStyle st
    End If
Next
End Sub

Sub DelSingleStyle(st As Style)
On Error GoTo BadStyle
Dim s As String
s = st.Name
Debug.Print " Try to delete: "; s
st.Delete
Debug.Print " Deleted: "; s
Exit Sub
BadStyle:
Debug.Print "Not Deleted: "; st.Name
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi and thank you for assisting on this. I implemented the code you shared which runs just fine and I find that it deletes all custom styles except for these last remaining 20-30 custom styles where the ID's include special symbols. I tried renaming the styles but this just leads to duplication instead of renaming.

Comment: Can you share a few names of these styles with the special chars

Comment: Not Deleted: AeE­ [0]_INQUIRY ¿µ¾÷AßAø 
 Try to delete: AeE­_INQUIRY ¿µ¾÷AßAø

Comment: In the comment above I pasted the console output from one of the styles that was not deleted in running your code. It's basically just a bunch of weird symbols but some of the names seems to also just include an underline as the only symbol "_".

Comment: I tried it with the given name, no problem. There is a different reason but it is hard to detect from here. There could be many reasons. My last idea is to save it as xlsm and look into the xml or try to delete with the code when xlsm

Comment: I tried saving it in the xlsm format and re-ran the various macros but no luck. I still get a debug error on the various '.Delete' statements in this case. Do you know of any other possible solutions I could try or should I make a new question that highlights my issue with these remaining styles with symbol names?

Comment: This will not be depending on the name, there must be another reason which blocks these styles:

Check: Unhide all sheets even the very hidden sheets - add  a new sheet, delete the other - if this helps check every sheet - especially very hidden and protected sheets

Check: has the workbook a relation- if yes try to remove

Check: remove all names in the workbook

Think of other checks

Answer (score 0):

With a minor modification of one of the Sub's you list above, all styles, including built-in styles (except "Normal", which cannot be deleted) are removed from the WorkBook.

```
Sub DeleteStyles()
    Dim sty As Style

    'On Error Resume Next 'outcommented as it is not needed
    For Each sty In ActiveWorkbook.Styles
        'If Not sty.BuiltIn Then     'outcommented as all styles should be deleted
        If sty.Name <> "Normal" Then 'except Normal, which cannot be deleted
            sty.Delete
        End If
    Next sty
    
    MsgBox "Macro completed" 'can be commented out
End Sub
```

You never answered to my question what you mean with "Special signs", but if you meant the `%` sign that occurs in some of the built-in styles, that is only the percentage (surprise!) of the color fill, e.g. "20% - Accent1" meaning a light fill.

Comment: It is just the custom styles I want to delete but the problem is that some of these are saved with several special symbols. I tried running your code but this returns a 1004 debug error on the 'sty.Delete' in the IF statement.